# Mod rewrite and issue with variable passing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the mod rewrite rule of my site
      `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

I am handling all inner pages from index.php
Now i want to pass parameter through url.
Suppose i have a page like site.com/settings
Now i want to pass parameter like site.com/settings?p=1

This is not working but `site.com/settings&p=1` is working.
Another thing is whenever i include any url like `site.com/settings?p=1` on settings page.

It starts to show strange behavior like site.com/settings starts redirecting to    site.com/settings?page=settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[L]` to `[L,QSA]`. That way apache adds the original querystring, instead of replacing it entirely.